# How to get RadioButton values from form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that writes out an Approve/Deny radio button for each record. I'm trying to figure out how to use the HttpPost to loop through each and determine if the radio button is selected and if so, which one was selected.

Doing some research I see that some use the Form collection for the form and in one example I found where the user used the forms ViewModel (which is what I normally do). However, when I try either one I'm coming up empty handed.

[image]

Here is my form. I'm writing out each record in a List to a table. I've tried both the Html.RadioButton and Html.RadioButtonFor to create them. I also have a comments textbox underneath the table where someone can put in some comments. Here is a snippet of the View.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.listPendingExceptions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.RadioButton("rdo" + item.RID, "A")</td>
            <td>@Html.RadioButton("rdo" + item.RID, "D")</td>
            <td>@item.Shift_Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ExceptionComment, new { cols = 200, @rows = 4, @maxlength = "100", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "100 character limitation", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

In my HttpPost I've tried using the form collection. However, what I've found is to look in the AllKeys list. When I view my Post the only thing in the AllKeys is the comment's TextBox value.

[image]

When I use a ViewModel in the HttpPost, the list of exceptions that I used to populate the table in the View is NULL. I would expect that since I didn't store the list in a hidden field.

[image]

How can I loop through each record, determine which if any radio button has been selected, as well as get the text from the Comments textbox?

***UPDATE for EditTemplate***

I created the folder structure for EditorTemplates in the Views.
[image]

I already had a ViewModel with a List of Exceptions but I did move the SelectedApproval from the main VM to the list of Exceptions.

```
public class ReportPendingExceptionsViewModel
    {
        public List<PendingException> listPendingExceptions { get; set; }

        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Required")]
        public string ExceptionComment { get; set; }
    } 

    public class PendingException
    {
        public int RID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Shift_Date { get; set; }
        public string Shift_Text { get; set; }
        public string Emp_Id { get; set; } 
        public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Comment_Text { get; set; }
        public string SelectedApproval { get; set; }
    }
```

I then created a Razor View for the Table rows.

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ViewModels.PendingException

<tr>
    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(e=>e.SelectedApproval,"A")</td>
    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.SelectedApproval, "D")</td>
    <td>@Model.Shift_Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
    <td>@Model.Emp_Name</td>
    <td>@Model.Shift_Text</td>
    <td>@Model.Comment_Text</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I then updated my main View to use the EditFor.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:80px;">Approve</th>
        <th style="width:80px;">Deny</th>
        <th>Shift Date</th>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Schedule</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(f => f.listPendingExceptions)
</tbody>
```

However, when I run it, all I get is the RID values. So, I must be missing something. Here is the output from the View Source.

[image]

Did I miss a step?

Comment: You need to show your models. You generating `name` attributes for the radio buttons which would have no relationship to your model.

Comment: I'm manually creating a name so that they group together. In other words I need an Approve/Deny per record that should be exclusive only for that record. The other records group name would have no effect on each other. The only way I could think to do that is use the unique record ID as part of the name. The thought there is that I could then get the RID from the name of the radio button so that I could use that to update the database record. I haven't finished out that piece of it to see if it will work the way I expect but it does group each record together like I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class ExceptionModel
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public bool IsApproved { set; get; }
        public DateTime ShiftDate { set; get; }
    } 

    public class MainModel  
    {
        public string Comment { set;get;}
        public List<ExceptionModel> lst_Exception { set;get;}
    } 

   //this is get request action method
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        MainModel model = new MainModel();
        model.lst_Exception = new List<ExceptionModel>()
        {
            new ExceptionModel() {Id = 1,IsApproved = false, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now},
            new ExceptionModel() {Id = 2,IsApproved = false, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now},
            new ExceptionModel() {Id = 3,IsApproved = false, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now}
        };

        return View(model);
    }

   //this is view for action method
    @model MainModel
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Approve</th>
              <th>Deny</th>
              <th>Shift Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @for (var item = 0; item < Model.lst_Exception.Count(); item++)
             {
                <tr>
                  <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>model.lst_Exception[item].IsApproved, "Approve")</td>
                  <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>model.lst_Exception[item].IsApproved, "Deny")</td>
                  <td><span>@Model.lst_Exception[item].ShiftDate</span>
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.lst_Exception[item].ShiftDate})
                  </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody> 
      </table>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Comment)
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
    }

//this is Post action method
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MainModel model)
{
  //here you can loop through model.lst_Exception to get the select values 
  //from the view 
}
```

Comment: I would like to learn about Editor Templates but going this route with a FOR loop does work.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do this with **Editor Templates**.

Start with creating a view model for pending exception items

```
public class ExceptionVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public bool? IsApproved { set; get; }
    public DateTime ShiftDate { set; get; }
}
```

and in your main view model, you will add a collection property which of of type 
 `List<ExceptionVm>`.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string Comment { set;get;}
   public List<ExceptionVm> PendingExceptions { set;get;}
   public MyViewModel()
   {
     PendingExceptions = new List<ExceptionVm>();
   }
}
```

And in your GET action you initialize the view model object, load the PendingExceptions property

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.ExceptionVms = new List<ExceptionVm>()
    {
        new ExceptionVm() {Id = 1, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)},
        new ExceptionVm() {Id = 2, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)},
        new ExceptionVm() {Id = 3, ShiftDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)}
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now, let's create an editor template. Create a new directory called `EditorTemplates` under `~/Views/YourControllerName/` or `~/Views/Shared/` and add a new razor view under that. Give the file the same name as our view model class, `ExceptionVm.cshtml`

Now add the below code to the editor template view. This basically render the 2 radio buttons and the date

```
@model ExceptionVm
<tr>
    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(b=>b.IsApproved, true)</td>
    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.IsApproved, false) </td>
    <td> @Model.ShiftDate   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)    </td>
</tr>
```

Now go to your main view, which is strongly typed to our MyViewModel class, and call the `Html.EditorFor` helper method and pass the `PendingExceptions` collection property to that

```
@model MyViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(f => f.PendingExceptions)
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Comment)
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

The call to the EditorFor will render a table row for each item in the `PendingExceptions` collection. When you submit the form, you can use the same MyViewModel class as the parameter and inspect the `PendingExceptions` property, iterate through each item and see whether it is `true` or `false` or `null`(if they have not selected anything)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
{
  // check model.PendingExceptions collection and each items IsApproved prop value
 // to do  : return something
}
```

If you do not want to allow null selection, change the IsApproved property type from `bool?` to `bool`

Comment: @Shyju...thanks for your continued help! This is my first EditFor template and I'm trying to follow along with your example but I must have missed something. I updated my original post with the what I did. Can you see what I might have missed?

Comment: With the code you posted, it should work fine. Do you have another editor template for the same class ? What version of MVC is your app is built with ?

Comment: Can you create a new MVC project and just add the code i have in my answer and try whether it works ? If not, share it and i will take a look.

Comment: No other editor template, this is my first attempt at one. Should be MVC 5 application. I'll test on a simple project with your code because I would like to learn about Editor Templates. I've seen them talked about but I've never implemented one. I'll have to wait a couple of days before I can do that because I have to get some of these pages done for an initial demo in a couple days. Thanks.